# Tags - Singular or plural term?

Tags: discussion, tags

Jonathan created a new tag `tab` (as in [vertical tabs](https://developer.blender.org/D75)):

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tab

Now I wonder if both, singular and plural forms are acceptable, or if either of them is **prefered**? Existing tags seem to use plural over singular. And I would actually like `tabs` more.

Or should it even be `vertical-tabs`, to explicitly refer to this new UI feature?

Comment: As a general rule of thumb, it's often best to go for the pluralized form when creating new tags.

Answer (score 3):

Even though this is a new feature and it might help to filter these accordingly, I think this tag is too localized to one specific aspect of the UI, it's as useful as having a [buttons](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/buttons) and and [menu](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/menu) tag.

I propose synonymizing it into [interface](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interface).

Comment: Good point, I'd like to follow your suggestion and synonymize it - but... is it correct to suggest a synonym on [tag:tab], or do I suggest one for [tag:interface], in order to merge tab into interface?

Comment: @CoDEmanX The latter but no need to, I have already done so.